# Trouble solving a ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What I'm trying to solve is

$$ \frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{-x- y^3}{y - x^3}.$$

I've tried with substituting with $ v = \frac{x}{y} $ and $ u = \frac{y}{x},$ but even with that I still can't separate the variables.

Using the second substitution I get $$ ( u + x^3u^3 - x^2 + x )  dx + (u + u^4x^2) du = 0$$

I tried working with this but found no way to simplify or advance from this in any way. I plugged it in Wolfram Alpha and of course it gave a nice looking solution to this (an ugly one for the first form of the equation though), so I know I'm missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That ODE doesn't look very homogeneous to me...

Comment: @Hans you're right actually, I wasn't really thinking when I wrote the title.

Comment: You should try to find an integrating factor: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement Jack's answer, you might want to look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46698/help-with-solving-differential-equation-using-exact-equation-method/46707#46707) on how to proceed.
All the best.

Comment: I tried to find similar problems posted here but must have skipped this one, since I didn't know I was looking for the exact equation method. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome...glad to help..:)

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite it as $$(y-x^3)dx+(x+y^3)dy=0$$
and note that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(y-x^3)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+y^3)$$
Then you can go on yourself.

---

According to the substitution you used: $v=\frac{x}{y}$, I guess you were thinking about the homogeneous first-order differential equation which can be written in the
form 
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=F(\frac{y}{x})$$

This is different from the equation in your question.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to go from here, but at least I see what I should be doing. I don't have my books right now with me, so when I get home I'll take a look at what Javier suggested and try to solve this.